# Workflow unable to send email to my own email address. but can send email to others

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

```
RequestorId: 86ebc278-c778-c6bd-0000-000000000000. 
Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 
Exception details: System.ApplicationException: 
HTTP 400 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],
"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["194"],
"SPRequestGuid":["86ebc278-c778-c6bd-9166-0b06bd53d297"],
"request-id":["86ebc278-c778-c6bd-9166-0b06bd53d297"],
"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],
"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],
"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],
"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Tue, 21 Jun 2016 01:04:11 GMT"],
"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} 
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) 
at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, 
BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
```

Whenever I put my email address in the Email stage of the workflow and then run the workflow on the associated list the above error occurs, but if I put the email address of other person it works fine.

Comment: What kind of logic your workflow will perform on your email? e.g. check the username by the email?

Comment: the workflow will send me an email if some person fill up and submitted the infopath form.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error recently. It was because i had 2 user name enries-one under my old domain/user , and one under my new i:#0.w|domain\user claims. I can only send myself an email if i select myself as a specific user. I cannot just use my text name or email address. I'm not sure how i got 2 user names, must have happened during our 2013 migration